# Ruby - route returning a 200 status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my first Ruby app - I want to the root to return a 200 status code i.e. it would just be a health check.

Whats the correct way to do this - I tried the below with no luck:

`get('/' => 'outlets/healthcheck#index', :status => 200)`

Where I have a empty HTML file in the directory `outlets/healthcheck/index.html.erb`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
#routes.rb
root 'outlets/healthcheck#index'
```

Now in your `Outlets::HealthcheckController` you need to define an `index` action like this:

```
def index
  head 200
end
```

You also don't need to have a file in views category related to this action.

Comment: Cool - did that but I keep seeing: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route: [GET] "/")`. I've tried `get('/' => 'outlets/health#index')` and `root(:to => 'outlets/health#index')`

Comment: Have you removed any other modifications to root you might have done in your `routes.rb`? If so, I'd need to see the whole file.

Comment: Ah cool - got it - I was placing the route inside another outlet. I took it out and its ok